# Pine v5 script - why isn't this percentage conversion working?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I have a TradingView Pine v5 strategy script that buys if the price closes a certain percentage below the set EMA level and sells if the price closes a certain percentage above the same EMA level.

Here's the working code for that:

```
// EMA Length
emaLength = input.int(title="EMA Length", defval=200, minval=0)

// EMA Price Percentages
emaPercBuy = input.float(title="Buy % Below EMA", defval=1.006, minval=0, step=0.001)      // 1.006 means 0.6%
emaPercSell = input.float(title="Sell % Above EMA", defval=1.006, minval=0, step=0.001)    // 1.006 means 0.6%

// EMA Line Function
emaLine = ta.ema(close, emaLength)

// EMA Plot line
plot(emaLine, color=close[1] > emaLine and close > emaLine ? colorGreen : colorRed, linewidth=2)

// Buy and Sell
longCond = close < emaLine/emaPercBuy
shortCond = close > emaLine*emaPercSell
```

`defval=1.006` is 0.6% as a decimal and the line `longCond = close < emaLine/emaPercBuy` divides the EMA by that decimal number (aka "emaPercBuy") to reduce the EMA level by -0.6%. That all works fine, but it looks messy putting `1.006` and I want to be able to put `0.6` in the input.

That means making the code do a calculation so if I do `0.6 +100 /100` that converts it back to what the code needs to use `1.006`

With that in mind I altered the code to allow normal looking percentages to be put in, but this doesn't work - it doesn't show any trades on the chart:

```
// EMA Length
emaLength = input.int(title="EMA Length", defval=200, minval=0)

// EMA Price Percentages
emaPercBuy = input.float(title="Buy % Below EMA", defval=0.6, minval=0, step=0.1)
emaPercSell = input.float(title="Sell % Above EMA", defval=0.6, minval=0, step=0.1)

// EMA Line Function
emaLine = ta.ema(close, emaLength)

// EMA Plot line
plot(emaLine, color=close[1] > emaLine and close > emaLine ? colorGreen : colorRed, linewidth=2)

// Buy and Sell
longCond = close < emaLine/emaPercBuy+100/100
shortCond = close > emaLine*emaPercSell+100/100
```

The line `close < emaLine/emaPercBuy+100/100` should be the right calculation but it's not working - no trades appear on the chart unlike with the first block of code above that does work - but that looks messy with 1.006 to mean 0.6%.

I don't know why doing `+100/100` hasn't fixed it and since that is the correct calculation, I don't know what else I could try. It seems even though the code compiles, there's something simple I have overlooked?

Thanks in advance to anyone Pine coders that can answer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `longCond = close < emaLine/emaPercBuy+100/100`, you are simply adding `1` to the result of `emaLine/emaPercBuy`.

That expression will be evaluated as `(emaLine/emaPercBuy) + (100/100)`.

I would do this in another way. I would get the percentage value in place like so:

```
emaPercBuy = input.float(title="Buy % Below EMA", defval=0.6, minval=0, step=0.001) * 0.01
```

Then calculate the value without modifying `emaPercBuy` later on like below:

```
longCond = (emaLine * (1 - emaPercBuy))
```

Otherwise, you need to convert `emaPercBuy` to percentage every time you use it.